# Ansible ec2_vpc_net and ec2_vpc_subnet - where to set subnet default public ip

Tags: ansible, amazon-ec2, aws-vpc

Since upgrading to these 2 Ansible modules I am having difficulties in setting the subnets to have default public IP when new instances are created by autoscaling?

I can't find any setting on the documentation for this, how do I achieve this?

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_vpc_net_module.html

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_vpc_subnet_module.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map_public parameter set to true in the second link should do this.